# Migration run will execute rb files under 'config/initializers/' firstly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

Is it so that if I run '**rake db:migrate**' to run the latest migration, the files under '**config/initializers/**' will be triggered to run firstly?

At least, when I create migration with '**rails generate migration XXXX**' command, the ruby files under '**config/initializers/**' will run firstly... So, I would like to know is it so that all the initializer files will be run before migration run?

Comment: Yes... Environment files are needed because in running migration files so many things are required like database connection, model etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During a migration the full Rails environment is setup, so **YES**, the initializers in `config/initializers` will be run before the migrations.